# How to define reset and cancel function in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope, crud

The currently problem is as follows. I've a Controller who manages the CRUD operations. In future I will do it in a service. However in my Controller is the following Code for my reset-fn:

```
var oldItem = angular.copy($scope.selectedItem);

//reset btn
$scope.reset = function () {
   $scope.selectedItem = oldItem;
}

//cancel btn
$scope.cancel = function () {
   $scope.selectedItem = oldItem;
   $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
}
```

Imagine my View. I have a table list with items. When you click on one of these rows it is opening a modal window with a form and the values of the columns. When I do some changes and click on reset btn then I get the old values but only in the form in modal window and when I click on cancel btn then the window is closed but the changed value remains in the table list.
I've tried some abilities with $rootScope and $broadcast but it doesn't work. Have anyone an idea?

Comment: Shouldn't the code be `$scope.selectedItem=oldItem;`?

Comment: Sorry I've changed my post. :D

Comment: The problem is the same.

Comment: Can anyone help me for this problem??